# Obtener porcentaje de uso de CPU en javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en node para obtener el porcentaje de uso del procesador, he intentado obtenerlo a partir de los times del modulo os, pero difiere mucho de lo que muestra en el administrador de tareas.

He intentado con esto:
https://gist.github.com/bag-man/5570809

EDIT:
al final decidi usar este modulo https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cmd
para ejecutar el comando wmic cpu get loadpercentage y asi obtener el porcentaje

Comment: En windows [loadavg()](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_loadavg) retorna `[0, 0, 0]`

Comment: si, el loadavg() solo funciona en unix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te puedo sugerir que utilices pidusage: https://github.com/soyuka/pidusage
Aparentemente es mas complicado de lo que parece lo que vos buscás.

Ejemplo de la documentación:

```
var pusage = require('pidusage')

pusage.stat(process.pid, function(err, stat) {

    expect(err).to.be.null
    expect(stat).to.be.an('object')
    expect(stat).to.have.property('cpu')
    expect(stat).to.have.property('memory')

    console.log('Pcpu: %s', stat.cpu)
    console.log('Mem: %s', stat.memory) //those are bytes

})

// Unmonitor process
pusage.unmonitor(process.pid);
```